# How to pass securely SSH Keys to Docker Build?

Tags: ssh, docker, ansible, ansible-pull

I want to create a Docker image for devs that reproduces our production servers. Those servers are configured by Ansible.

My idea is to run an `ansible-pull` to apply all the configuration inside the container. The problem is that I need the SSH key to pull the playbook, but I don't want to share the SSH key on the Docker image.

So, there is a way to have the SSH keys on build time without having them on run time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice question. The simple way to do it is by removing the SSH keys after the Ansible stuff in the build - but because Docker stores images as layers, someone could still find the old layer with the keys in it.

If you build this Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu                                                                       
COPY ansible-ssh-key.rsa /key.rsa                                                    
RUN [ansible stuff]
RUN rm /key.rsa
```

The final image will have all your Ansible state and the SSH key will be gone **but** someone could easily run `docker history` to look at all the image layers, and just start a container from an intermediate layer before the key was deleted, and grab the key.

The trick would be to do something like this and then use [Jason Wilder's docker-squash tool](https://github.com/jwilder/docker-squash) to squash the final image. In the squashed image the intermediate layer is gone and there's no way to get at the deleted key.

Comment: Exactly that was the problem: that the info remained on the layers. Didn't know that you could squash te images. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd setup some local file serving facility available only in your build environment.
E.g. start lighttpd on your build host to serve your pem-files only to local clients.

And in your Dockerfile do add/pull/cleanup in a single run:

```
RUN curl -sO http://build-host:8888/key.pem && ansible-pull -U myrepo && rm -rf key.pem
```

In this case it should be done in a single layer, so there should be no trace of key.pem left after layer commit.

Comment: Sending private keys over HTTP doesn't sound very secure.

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution by using this repo, [dockito/vault](https://github.com/dockito/vault), 
Secret store to be used on Docker image building.

I create a service *dockito/vault* and *Ubuntu* image where I attach my private key to the volume and run it as a process using,

```
docker run -it -v ~/.ssh:/vault/.ssh ubuntu /bin/bash -c "echo mysupersecret > /vault/.ssh/key"

docker run -d -p 14242:3000 -v ~/.ssh:/vault/.ssh dockito/vault
```

And, here is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN apt-get update -y && \
      apt-get install -y curl && \
      curl -L $(ip route|awk '/default/{print $3}'):14242/ONVAULT >   
      /usr/local   
      /bin/ONVAULT && \
      chmod +x /usr/local/bin/ONVAULT
ENV REV_BREAK_CACHE=1
RUN ONVAULT echo ENV: && env && echo TOKEN ENV && echo $TOKEN
RUN ONVAULT ls -lha ~/.ssh/
RUN ONVAULT cat ~/.ssh/key
```

You can use the alpine linux to reduce final build size, and built the image as,

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t mohan08p/VaultTest .
```

And, you are done. You can inspect the image. Secrets has not stored inside the image as its empty.

```
docker run -it mohan08p/VaultTest ls /root/.ssh
```

This is good technique to pass the .ssh at the build time. Only disadvantage is I need to keep additional Vault service running.

Answer (score -1):

You could mount the SSH Keys into the Container on runtime.

```
docker run -v /path/to/ssh/key:/path/to/key/in/container image command
```

Comment: Can you expand on this? Right now it's only really a comment, not a full blown answer in its own right.

Comment: The problem is that I only need the SSH keys on build time.